# Nexus Prisma - How to handle createdAt and updatedAt with crud globally?

Tags: typescript, prisma, nexus-js

First thing I came up with, is by calling `computedInputs` in the `nexusPrisma` option. But it won't work since they need to be handled differently depending on the situation, but globally:

```
1. create -> createdAt = now, updatedAt = null
2. update -> createdAt = keep as it is, updatedAt = now
```

In order to make it work, I need to set computedInputs individually like so:

```js
t.crud.createOneX({
  computedInputs: {
    createdAt: () => DateTime.utc().toString(),
    updatedAt: () => null,
  },
});

t.crud.updateOneX({
  computedInputs: {
    createdAt: () => undefined,
    updatedAt: () => DateTime.utc().toString(),
  },
});
```

While this might work, I'm unable to "compute" these inputs on the nested models. In order to prevent passing createdAt/updatedAt, I have to create another `t.crud` on that resource as well, without these timestamps.

The last workaround for this that might work, is to not use `t.crud` at all, which is a bummer.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Thank you for asking the question.

Prisma can handle the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns for you in your models. Add the `@default(now())` and `@updatedAt` attributes to your `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns respectively. You can add the columns to your models like this:

```
model Post {
  id               Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  title            String
  content          String?
  published        Boolean?           @default(false)
  createdAt        DateTime           @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime           @updatedAt
}
```

You can learn more on the [`@default(now())`](https://prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#now) and [`@updatedAt`](https://prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#updatedat) in our docs.

In case you run into any other issues and queries, I'll be happy to help

Comment: I eventually ended up manually creating these fields. Felt more in control . PS - If you have just signed up in order to answer my question, then I just want to let you know that you're a legend.

Comment: When using `@default(now())` and `@updatedAt` set 2 differents timestamp when created, determine if a record have been updated using `createdAt !== updatedAt` always returns `true`.

Comment: Be aware that subsequently adding `createdAt` with `@default(now())` adds the current date. This may lead to wrong intepretation of the creation date later down the line.